# Observable's subscribe triggered twice

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

I've a problem with observable's subscribe. I've a `NotificationService` which I use for data transfer from the response any component to `NotificationComponent`. And now I need to get response from subscribe only **one time** but I get **twice**.

**Here is my NotificationService:**

```
export class NotificationSharedService {
    private emitChangeSource = new Subject<any>();
    changeEmitted = this.emitChangeSource.asObservable();

    emitChange(change: any) {
        console.log(change);
        this.emitChangeSource.next(change);
    }

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.changeEmitted;
    }
}
```

**From here I send current status for `NotificationComponent`:**

```
const setDefaultImageRequest = this.images.defaultImage(id_image)
    .map((data: ResponseService) => {
        return Image.createFromObject(data.data);
    })
    .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.defaultImage.id = data.id;
        this.propertyGalleryStatus = true;
        const status = {
            'message': 'Изображение по-умолчанию установлено успешно',
            'status': true
        };
        this.notificationShared.emitChange(status);

    }, (errors) => {
        console.log(errors);
        this.propertyGalleryStatus = true;
    });

    this.subscriptions.push(setDefaultImageRequest);
```

**Here is my `NotificationComponent` where I subscribe:**

```
constructor(public sharedData: NotificationSharedService) {
    const getSharedData = this.sharedData.getData().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.status = false;
        this.statusError = false;
        this.state = true;
        if (data.internet_connection !== undefined) {
            if (!data.internet_connection) {
                console.log(data);
                this.message = this.messages.internet_error;
                this.statusError = data.statusError;
                console.log(this.message);

                return;
            }
        }

        this.message = data.message;
        this.status = data.status;
        this.statusError = data.statusError;

        this.fadeNotification = setTimeout(() => {
            this.state = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.status = false;
            }, 5000);
            this.statusError = false;
        }, 4000);
    });

    this.subscriptions.push(getSharedData);
}
```

**Here is response Where subscribe triggered twice:**

[image]

**Here is screenshot where notification template triggered twice**:

[image]

**Here is notification template**

```
<div on-mouseover="hoverNotification()" on-mouseout="unhoverNotification()" [ngClass]="{sbNotificationActive: state, sbNotificationSuccess: status, sbNotificationFailure: statusError}" class="sb-notification">
<div class="sb-notification__wrapper">
    <div class="sb-notification__box">
        <span class="sb-notification__message">{{message}}</span>
        <a *ngIf="!linkStatus" role="button" (click)="reloadPage()" class="sb-notification__reload">Reload page</a>
    </div>
    <div (click)="close()" class="sb-notification__close-button">
        <i class="sb-notification__icon flaticon-cancel"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us @Component decorator in NotificationComponent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get multiple outputs from one Subscription subscribing one Observable. Your service is a Singleton. In your **NotificationService** this `console.log(change);` and in **NotificationComponent** this `console.log(data);` prints that message multiple times. Remove that `console.log()` from **NotificationService** and you should see only one output.

Comment: On the screenshot You can see that console triggered twice only on the line 29.

Comment: I added new screenshot where You can see that notification div triggered twice

Comment: Can you show how you put data into template? As if it prints twice it means there are two Subscriptions

Comment: Yeah sure.I added

Comment: And how you display that notification? As this template is rendered twice right? How you turn it on?

Comment: I'm passing object with message and status: true and when I get this obj in Notification component my State of Notification become True and  I'll render it

Answer (score -2):

You can use simple flag to prevent this.

```
this.isDataLoaded = false;

// use OnInit instead of constructor
constructor(public sharedData: NotificationSharedService) {                                             
    const getSharedData = this.sharedData.getData().subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    if(this.isDataLoaded) { this.isDataLoaded = false; return; } 
    if(!this.isDataLoaded) {
      this.isDataLoaded = true;
      // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a real anti-pattern of rxjs. What happens if the data changes? Then you will never get the new data.